# Creating a tweet match table to pre-determined word list

Tags: r

I'm relatively new to R - currently using Studio v.0.99.879 - and what I've been mostly using it for has been sentiment analysis. But the other day I had a client ask if its possible that along with sentiment analysis I could output a .csv table with the top 5 words as column headers and the tweet text as rows and if there's a match between one of the header word(s) and the tweet text set/score a 1, else 0. If your familiar with using get_nrc_sentiment and then cbind'ing the sentiment output with the tweet text this will make sense. This would probably be a function.

If this is do-able I would appreciate any guidance.

Output example...

```
                               hot nice day test concert
   love the hot dogs            1   0    0   0     0
   hate summer school           0   0    0   0     0
   have a nice day              0   1    1   0     0
   enjoyed last nights concert  0   0    0   0     1
   where is waldo               0   0    0   0     0
```

Comment: Seems possible.  The responses you get will likely be better and more detailed if you can provide a minimal reproducible example.  You'll also want to indicate which packages you're using.

Comment: See the [tidytext](https://github.com/juliasilge/tidytext) vignettes.

Comment: @Jota          Thanks for the reply. I've updated my question.

Comment: @alistaire     thanks for the suggestion, enjoy Julia Silge's data science blog.

Comment: What are you starting with? If you've got a single-column data.frame of tweets and a vector of words, `data.frame(df, sapply(words, grepl, df$text) * 1)`. Adjust as necessary.

Comment: @alistaire     That piece of code worked exactly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a document-feature matrix.

Let's assume your tweets are stored as a character vector called `tweets`. I'd recommend using the package `quanteda`.

```
df_matrix <- dfm(tweets, tolower = TRUE, stem = FALSE, remove_numbers = TRUE,
                 remove_punct = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE)
```

This will form a matrix where each row is a tweet and each column is a word.

Then to sort the matrix so the most common words are come first:

```
df_matrix <- dfm_sort(df_matrix, decreasing = TRUE,
                      margin = "features")
```

You can simply take the first 5 columns of this new matrix and there you go!